# How add an attribute scoped in JSON in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

My aim is to add an attribute scoped in JSON, this some code :

```
User <ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reviews

Review<ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :best, lambda { |n| where('reviews.rating > ?',n}
```

And in my UsersController I want to do something like that :

```
format.json{
      render :json => @user.to_json :include=> :reviews.best
```

I've tried as well something like :

```
format.json{
      render :json => @user.to_json :include =>{ :reviews => {:method => best} }
```

But it doesn't work...

Any ideas ? 
Thank you very much !

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not using render correctly and there isn't an "include" option. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In my user JSON I want to get, not all reviews from this user, but only best reviews : Reviews.best.
For example user: "{user_id:1,name:vincent,reviews:[{r1},{r2},{..}]} whereas although there are 50 reviews for user 'vincent' ! 
do I make myself clear? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a gem for this, there is [Active Record Serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) which should fit your needs or also [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), there is a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl) for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out ! This is a solution : 
In the User model we can add a virtual attribute like

```
def best_reviews
   self.reviews.best
end
```

Then when we create json we can add :

```
format.json{
  render :json => @user.to_json :methods => %w(best_reviews)
}
```

It does work ! But I don't know if it's the best solution